# css files not loading and showing 301 Moved Permanently (from disk cache)

Tags: php, laravel

I have a laravel 5.0 project and our css files have stopped working and are showing the error 301 Moved Permanently (from disk cache) but when I put the link in chrome it shows the content so really confused..

I saw some posts about web.config and I put it in the public directory but no go.

any help on this will be really helpful

Comment: Some code would be helpful. Like the path (absolute/relative) of your static js/css files, along with the relative path of your controller files. May be a screenshot of the networks tab from chrome where you see the 301's as well.

Comment: this strange error sometimes happens on Laravel,
clear all of the cache folder, session folder, browser cache (most likely it won't work again)
try to change your CSS file name and run again.

Comment: The problem got stranger.. this link is loading twice and once it loads with 200 and once with 301.. I don't understand why